# How fill a Particular Combobox in a datagridview basedon selection of another combobox in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.NET.

I Have a Datagridview with the Datasource  of a Datatable. It has two Combobox. I am using the following code for fill a particular combobox in a datagridview  basedon selection of another combobox in VB.NET.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    Dim cmb As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
    If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
        If (cmb IsNot Nothing) Then
            RemoveHandler cmb.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged)
            AddHandler cmb.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
        Dim comboBox As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
        Dim cbCell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells(2), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
        s = comboBox.Text
        If String.Compare(s, "Driver") = 0 Then
            cbCell.Items.Clear()
            con.Open()
            cmd = New SqlCommand("Select EmpName from EmployeeDetails where Status='Active' and Designation='Driver'", con)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While (dr.Read())
                cbCell.Items.Add(dr("EmpName"))
            End While
            dr.Close()
            cmd.Dispose()
            con.Close()
        End If
    End If
 End Sub
```

It's working fine but when i was close the form and repoen then, i was wriiten the following code to fill the datagridview

```
Public Function view()
    con.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("select SalaryDate,Type,EmpName,StDate,EnDate,Months,Days,ActualSalary,ReceivedSalary,Balance from LeaseDriverSalary where LeaseNo=" + sele.ToString, con)
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    dt = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)
    Dim row As DataSet1.LeaseDriverSalary1Row
    j = 1
    For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
        row = DataSet1.LeaseDriverSalary1.NewRow
        DataSet1.LeaseDriverSalary1.Rows.Add(row)
        row.SalaryDate = dt.Rows(i)(0)
        row.Type = dt.Rows(i)(1).ToString
        row.EmpName = dt.Rows(i)(2).ToString
        row.StDate = dt.Rows(i)(3).ToString
        row.EnDate = dt.Rows(i)(4).ToString
        row.Months = Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows(i)(5).ToString())
        row.Days = Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows(i)(6).ToString())
        row.ActualSalary = Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows(i)(7).ToString())
        row.ReceivedSalary = Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows(i)(8).ToString())
        row.Balance = Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows(i)(9).ToString())
    Next
    j = 0
    cmd.Dispose()
    con.Close()
    Return 0
 End Function
```

Here the the second combobox wasn't fill based on the first combobox.
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

when re opening the window, what would cause a SelectedIndexChanged on the first ComboBox ? Put the code of your SelectedIndexChanged in a function 'UpdateSecondComboBox', then call it both in your SelectedIndexChanged handler and in your View() function.

Comment: thanks Vincent, i am calling the View function in form load itself, That time it wouldn't cause the SelectedIndexChanged function.